# How do I reinstall Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 13.10 and Apache which I use to host Rails sites.

Yesterday I decided to do a release upgrade before applying a shellshock patch `$do-release-upgrade`. The upgrade failed with a broken pipe error (I should have made a note of the exact error but didn't — sorry). I logged back in and the Ubuntu version remains the same. I noticed that Apache didn't restart so tried to start it up myself `$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` but I'm getting an error:

```
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load
/home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.19/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
into server: /home/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.19/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so:
undefined symbol: unixd_config
Action 'start' failed.
```

I've read that this type of error can happen when upgrading from Apache 2.2 - 2.4. I'm not 100% what version I was on before (or if it even upgraded yesterday — I'm assuming it did but feel free to tell me if I'm making stupid assumptions) but currently Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) is installed.

Is there a way for me to re-install Apache 2.2? (Is this even likely to rectify my issue or is there a better solution that I should try out?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem isn't Apache. It's Phusion Passenger. You installed Phusion Passenger against an older Apache version. Then you upgraded your OS, which upgraded Apache too, so that broke Phusion Passenger and now Apache refuses to start.

The solution: reinstall Phusion Passenger, so that it is recompiled against your current Apache version. Don't reinstall Apache; that doesn't help.